# Update more than one field in a table, having one field depending on the other

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am having problems to update 3 values from a table.

I am using the following code:

```
UPDATE tblOperation 
SET  
tblOperation.DateDifference = DateDiff("d",[tblOperation].[Date],[tblOperation].[FinalDate]), 
tblOperation.Tax = tblOperation.Value*tblOperation.Percentage/3000*tblOperation.DateDifference, 
tblOperation.FinalValue = tblOperation.Value-tblOperation.Tax;
```

The problem is that it is updating only the DateDifference value. To update the other fields, I have to run the code two more times...

How to do it in a single run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work in one query like that because the second and third updates are using the value of the previous columns. Since they are all updated in a Set you have to calculate them as well. You can't just use the column name. Basically it doesn't update each column synchronously.

```
UPDATE tblOperation 
    SET  
    tblOperation.DateDifference = DateDiff("d",[tblOperation].[Date],[tblOperation].[FinalDate]), 
    tblOperation.Tax = tblOperation.Value*tblOperation.Percentage/3000*(DateDiff("d",[tblOperation].[Date],[tblOperation].[FinalDate])), 
    tblOperation.FinalValue = tblOperation.Value-(tblOperation.Value*tblOperation.Percentage/3000*(DateDiff("d",[tblOperation].[Date],[tblOperation].[FinalDate])));
```

Comment: You calculate those in the update statement. How I have it in the answer.